# Prove the order of an element is the order of the group

Tags: group-theory

If $g \in G$ and $|G| = n$, prove $g^n = e$.

I actually don't know if this is true or not, which is why I am trying to prove this. I know that the order of $g$ is $n$, but I don't really understand what the order of an element means. I know that when you apply the group's operation to that element by itself $n$ number of times, you get the identity element, but I don't know how that helps prove or disprove this.

Comment: Have you heard of Lagrange's theorem? Note that the order of a group element is defined as the *least* positive $n$ such that $g^n=e$. (If $g^n=e$, then $g^{2n}=e$, $g^{3n}=e$, etc.) The correct statement of your claim is that the order of each element *divides* the order of the group.

Comment: "I know that when you apply the group's operation to that element by itself n number of times, you get the identity element" Try writing that down in formulas. What do you get?

Comment: @Joshua: If the order of $g$ is $2n$, that does divide $n$ but then it's not an integer. Is that okay?

Comment: @user130018 When we say $a$ divides $b$, we mean "there exists an integer $k$ such that $b=ak$". So, no, you can't say that $2n$ divides $n$ (unless $n=0$). But the result that you are asking to prove is considerably more sophisticated than this - it requires Lagrange's Theorem, which takes a fair amount of work to prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the subgroup of $G$ generated by $g$. By Lagrange, the order of $\langle g\rangle$ divides $n = |G|$. But the order of this subgroup is precisely the order of $g$!

So if the order of $g$ is $k$, we have that: $k|n$, that is: $n = kt$ for some (positive) integer $t$.

Hence $g^n = g^{kt} = (g^k)^t = \dots$?

Comment: You say that $k|n$, but how do you know the order of an element divides the order of the group? Is it a corollary of Lagrange's Theorem? And to answer your question, it is $=e$?

Comment: Yes, since $|g| = k$, we have $g^k = e$ (note this is "one way", we in general CANNOT say $g^k = e \implies |g| = k$) and thus: $g^n = e^t = e$.